# What is going wrong with this javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am trying to post the whole json as a table format but cant find a reason why it just says "object object" etc i tried changing the const data to " const {orderid, customer, customerid } = await response.json
but then it doesnt do anything. like  when I open that json file in console the arrays are numbered from 0-75 and there are objects named orderid, customer etc. so what I'm doing from and how do open all of the arrays on the site in table form

```js
async function loadIntoTable(url, table) {
  const tableHead = table.querySelector("thead");
  const tableBody = table.querySelector("tbody")
  const response = await fetch("https://www.cc.puv.fi/~asa/cgi-bin/fetchOrders.py");
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data)
  
  //puhdista
  tableHead.innerHTML = "<tr></tr>";
  tableBody.innerHTML = "";
  
  // lollero
  for (const dataText of data) {
    const dataElement = document.createElement("th");
    dataElement.textContent = dataText;
    tableHead.querySelector("tr").appendChild(dataElement);
  }
}

loadIntoTable("https://www.cc.puv.fi/~asa/cgi-bin/fetchOrders.py", document.querySelector("table"));
```

```css
.table {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table thead th {
  background: cadetblue
}

.table td,
.table th {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: white;
}

.table tbody tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show an example of the JSON you get back from that URL.

Comment: You can't just dump an object into HTML. You need to individually work with the properties.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually choose a property for the title e.g

```
dataElement.textContent = dataText.customer;
```

Otherwise you're trying to make the whole object the title.

```js
async function loadIntoTable(url, table) {
  const tableHead = table.querySelector("thead");
  const tableBody = table.querySelector("tbody")
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  // console.log(data)
  
  //puhdista
  tableHead.innerHTML = "<tr></tr>";
  tableBody.innerHTML = "";
  
  // lollero
  for (const dataText of data) {
    const dataElement = document.createElement("th");
    dataElement.textContent = dataText.customer;
    tableHead.querySelector("tr").appendChild(dataElement);
  }
}

loadIntoTable("https://www.cc.puv.fi/~asa/cgi-bin/fetchOrders.py", document.querySelector("table"));
```

```css
.table {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table thead th {
  background: cadetblue
}

.table td,
.table th {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: white;
}

.table tbody tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Okey, can u call and whole array to table form ? or do i need to do object only